# Why is the EventListener not working as intended?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I defined two EventListeners:
I want to disable my custom alert as soon as the user writes smt in the inputs or click any buttons in the document.

```
var input = document.querySelector('#input');
input.addEventListener('input', hideAlert);

var toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  toggleForms();
  hideAlert();
});
```

But the EventListener does not get called

Here is the full JS Code:

```
var input = document.querySelector('#input');
input.addEventListener('input', hideAlert);

var toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  toggleForms();
  hideAlert();
});
function toggleForms() {
    var toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
    var RegBtn = document.getElementById('RegBtn');
    if (loginForm.style.display === 'none') {
    loginForm.style.display = 'block';
    registerForm.style.display = 'none';
    toggleButton.textContent = 'Registrieren';
    RegBtn.textContent = 'Anmelden'
    } else {
    loginForm.style.display = 'none';
    registerForm.style.display = 'block';
    toggleButton.textContent = 'Anmelden';
    RegBtn.textContent = 'Registrieren'
    }
    }
function hideAlert() {
    var alert = document.querySelector('.alert');
    alert.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your html code

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Dev Console? There could be an error message waiting for you.

Comment: It would be great if you can add HTML code as well.

Comment: The HTML Code: [link]https://pastebin.com/hpNi0ygt

Comment: The Console shows no errors

Comment: Just a guess - Are you creating the input dynamically? i.e. after the event listener is declared? Unless the listener is at document level, it will not know about elements created later.

Comment: Please provide a [_minimal_, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ideally on StackOverflow to be independent of third-party sites and because code snippets can be included in questions (and answers!) directly.